# What is the 'ls option' which shows only the file size

Tags: ubuntu

My 'ls -la' output shows:

```
 $ ls -la test.img
-rw-rw-r-- 1 michael michael 3,871,716 Nov 23 17:22 test.img
```

What is the 'ls option' just show the size of the file?

When I do 'ls -s', the number does not match the one I get from 'ls -la'?

```
$ ls -s test.img
3,874,816 test.img
```

Answer (score 1):

`-s` gives the size in blocks.

Do you have some environment variables set that affect `ls`?

```
$ ls -l xml/iisx11b.xml
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ian ian 38984 Aug 10  2010 xml/iisx11b.xml

$ ls -ls xml/iisx11b.xml
44 -rw-rw-r-- 1 rgb rgb 38984 Aug 10  2010 xml/iisx11b.xml

$ ls -s xml/iisx11b.xml
44 xml/iisx11b.xml

$ ls -sh xml/iisx11b.xml
44K xml/iisx11b.xml
```

Comment: No, I don't. So what is the option to just give you '38984' in your example?

Answer (score 0):

`ls -s` shows the size in blocks including [indirect blocks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode_pointer_structure).

Answer (score 0):

Another option instead of `ls -sh` is `du -h` which estimates file sizes in the directory.  The -h means "human readable"  i.e. 444k 2G, etc.

It does so recursively, so in my documents folder with just a folder called super user would read:

```
12K    ./superuser/question00000-blah
20K    ./superuser
24K    .
```

I understand it is not the exact thing you are asking, but may be helpful in certain contexts for you.